# Using identical query params with QueryHelpers

Tags: c#, .net, uri, .net-5

I'm trying to generate an url like,

[www.example.com/Example?someOption=true&anotherOption=false&filter=testFilter&filter=testFilter2&filter=testFilter3](http://www.example.com/Example?someOption=true&anotherOption=false&filter=testFilter&filter=testFilter2&filter=testFilter3)

I have been using StringBuilder so far for the task but I'd like to think it's not the appropriate way of doing it. As a result, I came to conclusion that I should be generating this link using Uri class and not StringBuilder or any string extensions. Soon after, I came across [QueryHelpers.AddQueryString](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.webutilities.queryhelpers.addquerystring?view=aspnetcore-6.0). The issue with that is, it's using Dictionaries to add query parameters and adding an identical parameter ('filter' in my example) is just not possible.

Just wondering is there any other built in function or library that I can use to cleanly generate my urls with identical query parameters?

Comment: The is nothing wrong with using a string builder to create your URL.  When generating a string any method that give correct results and is easy to understand is appropriate.  I try to avoid using libraries when simple net methods can be used. Adding unnecessary libraries just increase the size of your executable and can increase the runtime of the code.

Comment: @jdweng saying "it's not appropriate" maybe was a little too harsh but it's definitely not as clean as I'd like it to be. Of course it does the job and works flawlessly - but it's error prone in a way that you can easily forget '?' and/or '&'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the overloads to `QueryHelpers.AddQueryString` takes an enumerable of key/value pairs.   This means you can create your own 'dictionary' like this:

```
var filters = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
{
    new KeyValuePair("filter","testFilter1"),
    new KeyValuePair("filter","testFilter2"),
    new KeyValuePair("filter","testFilter3"),
}
```

Then you can call

```
var uri = QueryHelpers.AddQueryString("www.example.com", filters);
```

Answer (score 0):

A little more elegant:

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetAsync(string url, Action<HttpRequestHeaders> headers, Action<HttpRequestParameters> parameters)
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            var _httpRequestParameters = new HttpRequestParameters();
            headers?.Invoke(client.DefaultRequestHeaders);

            if (parameters != null)
            {
                parameters.Invoke(_httpRequestParameters);
                var query = _httpRequestParameters.GetQueryString();
                url += query;
            }

            return await client.GetAsync(url);
        }
    }
```